# Querying on column having comma separated values

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have a 2 Mysql tables

1. Category

> ```
> id |  name 
> -----------
>  1 |  cat1
> ```

2. Item

> ```
> id |  name | cat_ids
> --------------------
>  1 |  prod1| 1,2,3
> ```

I have a use case where I get a category Id and I have to fetch all the related products.

I tried using like query. (If I give input as 1, it get products of not only 1 but also 11, 12... every number having 1 which is wrong)

I am using spring-boot + jpa in the project. I thought of doing this programmatically but there are thousands of records and iterating is not a feasible solution.

Please suggest

PS:
I know this is a very bad design. But this was passed to me and I have to deal with this.

Comment: can you post your query here? (the sql query you wrote) and the actual table structure for category and item

Comment: that's bad database design. each `cat_id` should be in its own cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have privilege to edit the db schema as mentioned by Martin Hennings .. u can use a condition : like '1,%' or like  '%,1,%' or like '%,1'  ... Assuming also that u have no spaces

Comment: Yes exactly though modifying the schema is better

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a poor database design.
You should have a third table `category_item_relation` or similar:

3. Category_Item_Relation

   > ```
   > id | cat_id | item_id
   > 1  |      1 |       1
   > 2  |      2 |       1
   > 3  |      3 |       1
   > 4  | ...
   > ```

Then you can simply query with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM Category
    JOIN Category_Item_Relation ON Category.id = cat_id
    JOIN Item ON Item.id = item_id
WHERE Category.id = ?
```

Comment: Note that id is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Note that if you don't design the database as explained by Martin, the performance of any query or programmatic solution will be appalling, as every row on Item will always have to be read.